# How to force Tornado to localize included html templates (or sub-templates)?

Tags: templates, localization, include, tornado

I try to made a simple tornado template with localization:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url("style.css") }}">
        <title>{{ _("Title") }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ _("Welcome")}}</h1>
        {% include "language.html" %}
    </body>
 </html>
```

The "Welcome string is displayed in the proper language I choose (French or English in my case). But the included templated is not translated (language.html):

```
<p>{{ _("LanguageChoice") }}</p>
```

appears like this

```
LanguageChoice
```

instead of the localized string

But both strings are in the CSV files :

```
EN:
    "LanguageChoice","Select your language"
    "Welcome","Welcome"
FR:
    "LanguageChoice","Choisissez votre langue"
    "Welcome","Bienvenue"
```

Does anyone has an idea why tornado does not process the included template? I also try with {% extends ... %} to check if the behaviour is different, but as expected: it's consistent, same result.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Fixed: when you include a template then you have to restart the application, only the python code triggers a server restart event when changed. HTML files and CSV file do not

Comment: Templates are not covered by autoreload, but if you're setting `debug=True` on your `Application` (or `compiled_template_cache=False`) the templates should still be reloaded automatically without restarting the server.

Comment: The CSV file, on the other hand, is only loaded once and there is currently no way to reload it without restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading http://tornado-babel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html where the localisation process is explained. Though most of the content is relevant for the standard tornado.locale module, tornado-babel extends the functionality and uses babel for `l10n` and `i18n`.

Cheers